# Align Absolute Position on Top Center in CSS/Styled Components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I have a back button and a title that I wanted to put on the top and they should be aligned.
My problem is how can I put the "Hello World" title to the top center while the back button on the top left?

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/heade-styled-components-forked-b3z3x?file=/src/Header.js:1030-1252)

```
 <HeaderTopContainer>
    <BackContainer>
      <BackArrow src="arrow.svg" alt="back" />
      <BackText> Back </BackText>
    </BackContainer>
    <Title>Hello World</Title>
  </HeaderTopContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/heade-styled-components-forked-yjirb?file=/src/Header.js

```
  <HeaderTopContainer>
    <BackContainer>
      <BackArrow src="arrow.svg" alt="back" />
      <BackText> Back </BackText>
    </BackContainer>
    <Title>Hello World</Title>
    <BackContainer></BackContainer>
  </HeaderTopContainer>

  const BackContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width:100px
  `;
```

check this, I put a dummy back button container after the title and give the same width as the left back button container

after that flex will do the job,

Note: the body has a margin of 8px as default, that make a scroll in it please undo that if not needed

Comment: What do you mean by margin of 8px. I can't see it?

Comment: your codesandbox code body have a margin (as default) - i don't know is it in your project, if you are not facing any issues , leave it

Answer (score 0):

In your css for the title use:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
```

and for the back button:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Comment: it may overlap in smaller screens

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using display: flex for the title row.

I have configured your [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/heade-styled-components-forked-v7jb0). Try this

You have to set `position: absolute` for the back button and move it to the left and add `display: block` to the title text and add `text-align:center` it will do.

for `BackContainer`

```css
.back {
display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 20px;
  }
```

for `Title`

```css
.title {
 display: block;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```